# Thornwatch - How does paying for Hero Actions work?

Tags: thornwatch

Reading the Thornwatch rules, I'm struggling to be clear about how hero actions are paid for and how much they cost.

There are two types of non-scenario based Hero Actions, "tracker" card ones every hero gets automatically and "action card" ones you slot onto your hero and then power by stacking cards underneath.

To pay costs, you discard cards up to that value. However, action cards need to be "powered" to use, by tucking other cards underneath them.

On a test run-through, I ended up with three related questions.

Do you also have to pay costs for "action cards" that you have powered? (e.g. you stack three "Brawn" cards under the action cards, and then have to also discard three brawn cards to use it?)

When you have used a "deck power", does it remain slotted onto your card to be re-used or do it and its "powering" cards get discarded?

Can you slot a card, power it, and use its action all on the same turn?

Comment: Appreciate this is a basic question, but having read the rules a couple more times, I *think* I understand this properly now, but I would appreciate confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of powers - tracker powers and action cards. In order to use either you must pay for them either with slotted cards or discarded cards. See page 14 / 15 of the rules.

1. If you have stacked power cards under an Action Cards, then when you activate that Action Card the Action Card and all the stacked cards that are powering it are discarded. You do not pay a second time with cards from your hand.
2. When using an Action Card that you had slotted on your Tracker, it and all stacked cards powering it are discarded. You don't get to keep the Action Card to re-use again later.
3. Yes you can slot, power then use an Action card in one turn, on the understanding that you can only Act once a turn. In this case I don't think there is a difference between stacking cards to power the Action Card or simply discarding straight from your hand to power the Action Card.

Comment: Brilliant, worked a lot of this out after re-reading the rules (the bit about discard is sort of buried in a paragraph), but amazing to have a proper answer finally.